# Tax implication for US based IRA/401K when retiring to Italy

Tags: taxes, us-citizens, italy

If a US citizen retires to Italy, becoming a resident in Italy, and using Italy as the country of tax residence, how will distributions from an IRA/401K be viewed by US IRS?   How is it viewed in Italy?

Comment: Why is this considered off-topic? This is a very important question.